# Why BroadcastReceiver received two same broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to use a BroadcastReceiver to receive new messages from a Service. but the BroadcastReceiver always receive a broadcast TWICE...
the receiver code:

```
private class RecentBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle messageBundle = intent.getExtras();
        IChatCSMessage message = (IChatCSMessage) messageBundle.get("message");
        String sender = message.getSender().getUserId();
        addRecentBuddy(sender.trim());
        recentBuddyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        allMessages.get(sender).add(message);
        Log.i("RECENT_RECEIVER", "RECEIVING MESSAGE:" + message.getMessage());
    }
}
public void initReceiver() {
    IntentFilter myIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    myIntentFilter.addAction("com.ichat.message");
    recentBroadcastReceiver = new RecentBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(recentBroadcastReceiver, myIntentFilter);
}
```

the broadcast is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.ichat.message");
intent.putExtra("message", message);
IChatClientService.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe your `initReceiver()` is called twice.. ?

Comment: Maybe you register it also in the manifest file ?

Comment: @fiddler no, just in java code

Answer (score 0):

You really don't offer any proof that in both cases the Intents contain the same extended data. I say this because a) you never log the incoming action, b) you don't get the extended data with the key "message" by calling getStringExtra() (if indeed the contents of that extended data is a String), and c) you don't provide us with a logCat listing.

I suggest these steps for debugging:

1. Call Log.i for the incoming Intent action
2. Call Log.i for the incoming Intent's value for the "message" key.
3. Post the results.
4. Post the code that shows exactly what the type and value of "message" are when you *send* the broadcast Intent

In short, your BroadcastReceiver is receiving two Intents, presumably both with the action "com.ichat.message". If the broadcast is only in one place in your app, then that place is being reached twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake where you may have put your broadcast receiver in your manifest.xml with an intent defined like this:

```
      <receiver android:name="RecentBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.ichat.message" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

And also created one in your code as in your sample.  This is actually create two intent filters, so you can remove the intent filter in your xml and you should only see one broadcast.